# PHP/SQL prevent writing certain times into table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I guess my question might have a simple solution, but I am stuck. 
I have a `MYSQL-Table` and a form. The user input fills in the form. The user has to provide a start time for the event. `e.g. 8:00 o'clock` and a duration of the event. The end time is calculated based on the duration. So if a event starts at 8, has a duration of `2 hours`, there will be `10:00` be written in the end-Time column.

The problem is now, how do I prevent, that users can fill in events at `9:00` since the room is blocked from `8 - 10`? 
I appreciate your help!
Cheers!

Comment: You check if the entered start time doesn't fall between an existing start and end time? What exactly are you asking?

Comment: In your PHP action page, you can check the timestamps between the startTime + 2 hours and the closed time to see if it is not above. See https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php

Comment: you can try between query start time and end time

Comment: you can add a flag column and when its booked set it to say 1 and on each updated use it to check if thats possible to book or not..

Answer (score 0):

after user submits form, you can take submitted time and check whether room is occupied in that time with this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM event as e
WHERE e.room = <room_number>
AND (<start_time_of_new_event> BETWEEN e.start_time AND e.end_time
    OR <end_time_of_new_event> BETWEEN e.start_time AND e.end_time)
```

*start_time_of_new_event* would be submitted start time value

*end_time_of_new_event* would be submitted start time + duration

*room_number* -> i just assumed you have more rooms, where events can take place

if this query returns 1 or more, room is occupied in submitted time.

If you would like to disable possibility to submit time in which room is occupied, you could select occupied time slots before displaying the form. And in script decide which times can be booked